# How to remove black borders from spin button

Tags: vba, excel

In trying to remove black border from spin button onclick
(btw, I'm very interesting about the reasons for this ugly black border)

```
Private Sub spin01_SpinUp()
... //some code
ch01.SetFocus // ch01 is a textbox
```

First click - there are no borders
Next click - borders are there
Next click - there are no borders - and so on
The same is for SpinDown()
Very strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those black borders are to let you know the spin button currently has focus. If you click on the textbox `ch01` on your userform, then the lines will go away. AFAIK there isn't any property to remove those Black Borders permanently.

What is happening in your case is the code transfers the focus to the textbox `ch01` and that is when you do not see the borders but when the focus comes back to the Spin Button, those black borders are back.

**Alternative**:

Use Two command buttons and replicate the functionality of the Spin Button. You can also change the `.Picture` to show arrows instead of text on the command button. See Screenshot Below

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Private Sub spin01_SpinUp()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
    wait 0.1
    ch01.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub spin01_SpinDown()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
    wait 0.1
    ch01.SetFocus
End Sub

Public Sub wait(ByVal nsec As Double)
    nsec = nsec + Timer
    While nsec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: 'Those black borders are to let you know the spin button currently has focus' - Why the end user must know what button has focus?  '...you do not see the borders but when the focus comes back to the Spin Button' - but the last line of code is to set focus on ch01 ! How it can move the focus after this line ?

Comment: ThankYou, Siddharth. It seems solved, but I'm still wondering about so simple - but so complicated feature. And again: Why the end user must know what button has focus? AnyWay, Thanks, again.

Comment: Apparently the focus is not being transferred to the textbox so I just gave a minor pause so that the focus can shift to the textbox. `Why the end user must know what button has focus?` Well this is a very basic question. `Focus` say on a textbox helps the user the identify the control where he can type. `Focus` say on a Command button can help you click on the control using a keyboard.